# Can't read data from redirected io

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe, stdout

I've written a relatively simply piece of code that polls a pipe that was redirected as stdout in a child process. But when the poll function returns and says data is ready, the read function always returns zero.

Is there any reason that stands out as to why this isn't working? When I wrote directly to the pipe from the child process to the parent process, it worked fine. I think I'm just redirecting the io incorrectly.

Here's the parent process code:

Note: all macros account for errors and print them to an error log.

```
pollData.fd = out.fd[ READ_INDEX ];
pollData.events = POLL_IN;
pollData.revents = 0;

printf( "Polling pipe for data...\n" );

if( poll( &pollData, 1, 5000 ) > 0 )
{
        int bytesRead = 0, trys = TRYS;
        printf( "Data has been received: " );

        Read:

        bytesRead = read( out.fd[ READ_INDEX ] , out.buf, BUF_SIZE );

             if( bytesRead > 0 ) printf( "%s" , out.buf );
        else if( bytesRead < 0 ) printf( "Error receiving data.\n" );
        else
        {
                trys--;
                printf( "No data was read.\n" );
                sleep( SLEEP );
                if( trys > 0 ) goto Read;
        }
}
else LOG( ERR_POLLING, 0 );
```

Here's the child process code:
Note: FD_REPLACE uses dup2 and closes the old handle.

```
FD_CLOSE_PACK(  out.fd[  READ_INDEX ],
                err.fd[  READ_INDEX ],
                 in.fd[ WRITE_INDEX ] );

FD_REPLACE( fileno( stdout ) , out.fd[ WRITE_INDEX ] , Child_Fail );
FD_REPLACE( fileno( stderr ) , err.fd[ WRITE_INDEX ] , Child_Fail );
FD_REPLACE( fileno( stdin  ) ,  in.fd[  READ_INDEX ] , Child_Fail );

printf( "This is a message from the test program!\n Hope it works!\n" );

sleep( 10 );

Child_Fail:

FD_CLOSE_PACK(  out.fd[ WRITE_INDEX  ],
                err.fd[ WRITE_INDEX  ],
                 in.fd[  READ_INDEX  ] );
return -1;
```

Here's one of the macros:

```
#define FD_REPLACE( old_fd, fd , addr )        
if( dup2( old_fd, fd ) < 0 )                                          
{ 
        LOG( ERR_DUP2, #old_fd " with " #fd );                 
        goto addr;           
}
```

Here's the output from the terminal:

```
Polling pipe for data...
Data has been received: No data was read.
No data was read.
No data was read.
No data was read.
No data was read.

Now closing...
```

Comment: What is the value of `pollData.revents` immediately after `poll` returns?  Does it have the `POLLIN` flag set?

Comment: no it wasn't, it was 16. i'm looking up what 16 means right now

Comment: it means POLLHUP, which seems to mean the device was disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I was replacing the file descriptors incorrectly. I replacing the wrong descriptor and I was doing it before I closed the old one. The code I posted above shows the old macro. The new macro is ( without error checking ):

```
#define FD_REPLACE( old_fd, fd, addr )
close( old_fd );
dup2( fd, old_fd );
```